# User table in Data Explorer not showing correct last visited date

Tags: support, users, data-explorer

I ran the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/271744) to get my last visited date:

```
select * from users where id=3936696
```

This is showing 2015-02-06 07:18:51. However I've visited the site yesterday, e.g. 2015-02-08 10:34 PM.

Can someone please help explain this, what happened here?

Comment: The database on http://data.stackexchange.com is only updated once a week, in the weekends, as far as I know.

Comment: You can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205012/did-my-contribution-based-on-the-timestamp-made-it-into-sede) to get the last date that is recorded in the different tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Data Explorer database is updated once a week, on Sunday morning UTC. The [homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) lists the approximate time of the last update at the top right-hand side:

> [image: relative date of update]

Instead, you could use the [`/users/{id}` API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) to look up the last access date for one or more users; the `last_access_date` field returned reflects the same information shown in a user profile (*seen ...*).

You can get *all* dates that *you yourself* visited by going to your profile page and clicking on your *visited* counter:

[image: visited counter highlighting days]

Days in green you visited. The information is not public and cannot be retrieved for other users.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this but Is there any way to get all previous visited dates for particular user?

Comment: @RahulNikate: no, there is not. That data is not public.

Comment: ... nor should it be.

Comment: @RahulNikate: you can get *your own* visited days in JavaScript form by visiting `URL:http://stackoverflow.com/users/daily-site-access/<your_user_id>`; it includes a `var visited = {...}` line which is a sparse array of dates you visited; outer object keyed by year, each year keyed by month, each month has keys for days you visited. The URL only works for your own user id, you'll have to be logged in.

Comment: 1009 consecutive.... shouldn't you get a life? ;)

Comment: @rene: I know, it's terrible. Boltclock has a 100% days visited == days consecutive record I'll never reach. Shame on me! *wait*, are you suggesting I spend *less* time here?!

Comment: @rene: [Anyone with a "visited: 2048 days, 2048 consecutive" in his/her profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976). Sooo far away.

Comment: @MartijnPieters VonC is very *gezellig*...